# Stability analysis of non-linear system outside of equilibrium point

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I have a non-linear system that comes from the transformation matrix for angular rotational rate from Euler -> Body frame:
$$
\dot{r} = A + sin(r)tan(p)B + cos(r)tan(p)C \\
\dot{p} = cos(r) B - sin(r) C
$$
where A, B, and C are constants. The equilibrium point is at:
$$
r_e = arctan(B/C)\\
p_e = arctan(-\frac{A}{B sin(r_e) + C cos(r_e)})
$$
When taking the Jacobian matrix and substitute the equilibrium point, I found that the real part of the eigenvalue is $$B cos(r)tan(p) - C sin(r) tan(p)$$
which always equals zero at the equilibrium point, so the system is marginally stable at the equilibrium point. This lead me to thinking that I need to check the system stability outside of the equilibrium point using Lyapunov theory. However, I've been struggling with finding the right candidate function.
When plotting the phase portrait of the system at some A, B, C values, I found that $r$ and $p$ seem to exhibit cyclical behavior like sine and cosine waves. For example, here's the
[phase portrait at A = 0, B = 0, C = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vetp.png)
However, after closer examination, they are not exactly sine and cosine waves. So something like $r^2 + p^2$ for the candidate function wouldn't work. Here's the [plot of r^2 + d^2 when simulated with dt = 0.0001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqOXP.png). It turns out that the radius is slower growing, so for this choice of A, B, and C, the system is unstable. For A = 0.1, B = 0.1, C = -1.0, the system is also unstable ([plot of r^2 + d^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bECoE.png)), but going a slower rate. I'm trying to find a candidate function where we can show that its derivative is positive depending on the choice of A, B, and C, but
I'm not sure how I should go about finding this candidate function, and if Lyapunov theory is not the suitable approach here, what other analysis should I look into?

Thanks

Comment: "which always equals zero at the equilibrium point, so the system is marginally stable at the equilibrium point." You can't conclude that for the original nonlinear system. Consider $\dot{x} = ax^{3}$, which has the linearization $\dot{z} = 0$. You can't conclude that the original system is marginally stable since if a<0 the system is stable but if a > 0 it is unstable. In your case, the linearization can't tell you anything about stability. Unfortunately, finding Lyapunov functions is hard.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense

Comment: Are you sure that for A = 0.1, B = 0.1, C = 1.0 the system is stable and that behavior isn't just a fluke from the ode solver you are using? Namely, I haven't been able to recreate your last plot.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Apologies, there seems to be a typo. C = -1.0 is what produces the plot I attached. I have updated my post to address this.

Comment: I get similar results when using C = -1.0. Also see my posted answer, in which I wasn't able to prove stability, but I at least showed that values of B and C separately don't characterize the behavior of the dynamics of the system. Instead it can be shown that the value of $R^2:=B^2+C^2$ does. So this also implies that the signs of B and C also don't matter.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen You're right! It was an issue with my solver. C = +/-1.0 produces the same result. Now I can't even find a combination of A, B, C that will produce a stable system anymore

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer, as I wasn't able to find a Lyapunov function, but hopefully this might at least might provide some insights into the dynamics of this system.

By performing a coordinate transformation it might lead to simpler dynamics, which allows for more insights of the dynamics of the system. Since common terms in the original dynamics are $\sin(r)$, $\cos(r)$ and $\tan(p)$, I propose the following coordinate transformation

\begin{align}
x &= B\,\sin(r) + C\,\cos(r), \\
y &= B\,\cos(r) - C\,\sin(r), \\
z &= \tan(p).
\end{align}

Which can be shown to have to following dynamics

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \left(B\,\cos(r) - C\,\sin(r)\right) \left(A + \left(B\,\sin(r) + C\,\cos(r)\right) \tan(p)\right) \\
&= y \left(A + x\,z\right), \\
\dot{y} &= -\left(B\,\sin(r) + C\,\cos(r)\right) \left(A + \left(B\,\sin(r) + C\,\cos(r)\right) \tan(p)\right) \\
&= -x \left(A + x\,z\right), \\
\dot{z} &= \sec(p)^2 \left(B\,\cos(r) - C\,\sin(r)\right) \\
&= y \left(1 + z^2\right).
\end{align}

By using $\sin(r)^2 + \cos(r)^2 = 1$, it can also be noted that

$$
x^2 + y^2 = R^2,
$$

with $R^2 := B^2 + C^2$. Using this proposed coordinate transformation it can be noted that the original coordinates $r$ and $p$ can only be recovered uniquely when assuming that $-\pi \leq r < \pi$ and  $-\pi/2 \leq p < \pi/2$. The equilibrium points of this transformed system can be shown to be $(x_{eq}, y_{eq}, z_{eq}) = (R, 0, -A/R)$ and $(x_{eq}, y_{eq}, z_{eq}) = (-R, 0, A/R)$. Evaluating the Jacobian at both equilibria yields the same following result

$$
J_{eq} =
\begin{bmatrix}
y\,z & A+x\,z & x\,y \\
-A-2\,x\,z & 0 & -x^2 \\
0 & 1+z^2 & 2\,y\,z
\end{bmatrix}_{eq} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
A & 0 & -R^2 \\
0 & 1+A^2/R^2 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

which similar to the original system only has eigenvalues for zero real part. So again nothing can be said about the local stability of the equilibria.

If one prefers to have a two instead of three dimensional system, one can reduce this system while introducing back some trigonometric functions. Since $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ holds and $y=0$ holds for both equilibria a natural choice would be to define the reduced coordinate as $x = -R\cos(\theta)$ and $y = R\sin(\theta)$ and scaling $z$ by $R$, i.e. $\sigma = R\,z$, results in slightly neater dynamics, resulting in

\begin{align}
\dot{\theta} &= A - \sigma \cos(\theta), \\
\dot{\sigma} &= \left(R^2 + \sigma^2\right) \sin(\theta),
\end{align}

with equilibria $(\theta_{eq},\sigma_{eq}) = (2\,k\,\pi, A)$ and $(\theta_{eq},\sigma_{eq}) = ((2\,k+1)\,\pi, -A)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. The corresponding Jacobians again have eigenvalues with zero real part, as shown below

$$
J_{eq} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma \sin(\theta) & -\cos(\theta) \\
\left(R^2 + \sigma^2\right) \cos(\theta) & 2\,\sigma \sin(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}_{eq} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \mp 1 \\
\pm\left(R^2 + A^2\right) & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I tried to find a Lyapunov function for each of the proposed transformed systems, but without success. I also tried limit my search to just Lyapunov functions whose time derivative is zero (using as starting point $V(x) = (x-x_{eq})^\top P\,(x-x_{eq})$ with $P\succ0$ and $J_{eq}^\top\,P + P\,J_{eq} = 0$), to at least ensure Lyapunov stability, but also without success.

Comment: This is great analysis! One question I have to confirm my understand is about how this shows that the value of B and C separate don't affect the stability. Is this because in your 3rd coordinate transformation, you show that the system no longer depends on B and C but just R? Or that in the 2nd transformation, the system only depends on A, and the initial condition only depends on R.

Comment: @Ryan Nguyen Both transformed systems imply this. Namely, in neither of their differential equations do C and B occur (in the first R only appears in the equality constraint). This can also be interpreted as adding a phase offset to $r$ from the original system.